# Default boolean value not being set Rails 4 Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created a migration to my users table with the following code:

```
add_column :users, :email_confirmed, :boolean, :default => false
```

however when a new user is created the `:email_confirmed` field is automatically set to `true`. Has this happened to anyone? Am I missing something simple? Any insights are welcome.

My User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower
    has_secure_password
    before_save { email.downcase! }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
    before_create :create_remember_token
  before_create :confirmation_token
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
      validates :email, presence: true, 
        format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
              uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
      validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, :unless => :email_activate

  def feed
     Micropost.from_users_followed_by(self)
  end

  def following?(other_user)
    relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  def follow!(other_user)
    relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  def unfollow!(other_user)
    relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy
  end

  def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def User.digest(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

  def email_activate
    self.email_confirmed = true
    save!(:validate => false)
  end

  def send_password_reset
      self.password_reset_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64.to_s
      self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
      save!(:validate => false)
      UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = User.digest(User.new_remember_token)
    end

    def confirmation_token
      # only generate if you did not manually set value
      if self.confirm_token.blank?
          self.confirm_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64.to_s
      end
    end
end
```

and my Users Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy
  before_action :registered_already, only: [:new, :create]

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
      @user = User.new
  end

  def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)    
      if @user.save
        UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
        flash[:success] = "Please confirm your email address to continue"
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        flash[:error] = "Ooooppss, something went wrong!"
        render 'new'
      end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    unless current_user?(user)
      user.destroy
      flash[:success] = "User deleted."
    end
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def confirm_email
    user = User.find_by_confirm_token(params[:id])
    if user
      user.email_activate
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:error] = "Sorry. User does not exist"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

   private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end

    def registered_already
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "You are already registered." if signed_in?
    end

end
```

my Sessions Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
      user = User.find_by_email(params[:email].downcase)
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      if user.email_confirmed
          sign_in user
        redirect_back_or user
      else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Please activate your account by following the 
        instructions in the account confirmation email you receieved to proceed'
      end
      else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
        render 'new'
      end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

I have a feeling that the email_activate method in the users model is being called on the create action but I don't know why?....

Just while I was doing this I commented out the `:unless => :email_activate' in the password validator. Now everything works. I am surprised that this was the reason as it does not make logical sense to my (admittedly somewhat limited) understanding of rails. Could someone explain why this was setting the email confirmed field to true please?

Comment: How do your schema.rb look? Also, can you insert your controller and the view that makes the form (or any other code you used to create the user).

Comment: Copying your code into a migration gave me an email_confirmed column defaulted to `false` as expected. Is it possible that the value is being altered from your model?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your help. I have added the requested code but in the mean time I have also fixed my problem, however I don't understand why it was a problem. Please see the last paragraph as I would appreciate some clearer insight into why this behaviour was happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the default value to always be set, you can't allow null values.  Specify `:null => false`

```
add_column :users, :email_confirmed, :boolean, :null => false, :default => false
```